# C# MVC Viewmodel data is not displaying in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a list of trades that are active/inactive, and I am looking to display a datatable in my View with a list of the active trades. Whenever I load the view I get an invalid JSON response. Troubleshooting the request with the browser I see that my response is just displaying the HTML of my view.

I am sure I am missing something incredibly obvious. For the record, in my controller action I have tried returning a couple different things to no avail (I will list them below)

My Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult TFSA()
{
    var trades = db.Trades.Where(t => t.AccountName == "TFSA" && t.Active == true).OrderBy(l => l.TradeID).ToList(); ;
    TradeIndexViewModel model = new TradeIndexViewModel()
    {
        ActiveTrades = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Trade>, List<ActiveTradesViewModel>>(trades)
    };

    return View();
    //return Json(new { data = model.ActiveTrades }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    //return Json(model.ActiveTrades, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    //return View(jsonModel);
}
```

The commented out returns are what I've attempted. When I was returning the JSON, my app would only display the JSON data (no HTML).

My ViewModels:

```
public class TradeIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ActiveTradesViewModel> ActiveTrades { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ClosedTradesViewModel> ClosedTrades { get; set; }
}

public class ActiveTradesViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Stock")]
    public string Ticker { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Shares")]
    public int Shares { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Avg Cost")]
    public float AvgCost { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Value")]
    public float BookValue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Market Value")]
    public float MarketValue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Daily Profit")]
    public float DailyProfit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profit")]
    public float Profit { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ROI")]
    public string ROI { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fees")]
    public float Fees { get; set; }
}
```

And my View:

```
@model InvestmentProject.ViewModels.TradeIndexViewModel

<html>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-flud">
        <table id="tfsaActiveTrades" class="table table-striped table-hover display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Shares</th>
                    <th>Avg Cost</th>
                    <th>Book Value</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Market Value</th>
                    <th>Profit/Day</th>
                    <th>Profit</th>
                    <th>ROI</th>
                    <th>Fees</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
</body>
</html>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#tfsaActiveTrades').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/TFSA",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "Ticker",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "Shares",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "AvgCost",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "BookValue",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "Price",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "MarketValue",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "DailyProfit",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "Profit",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "ROI",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "Fees",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "searchable": true
                },
            ],
        });
    </script>
}
```

I'd also be happy with a different way of displaying what is in my activetrades viewmodel.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the **`model`** object into the **View** that will be rendered, which goes like this:

```
return View(model);
```

Then you also need to define the body part of the table, and generate rows and cells.

After the closing `</thead>`, insert this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ActiveTrades)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Prop1</td>
            <td>@item.Prop2</td>
            ( .... etc.... )
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Use your actual property names instead of these examples.

By doing it this way you can leave out all the Ajax code, it won't be needed.

Comment: I tried removing the ajax code and running it like that but then my table is getting no data

Comment: I updated the answer to also generate rows and cells.